# Excel VBA update bubble chart dynamic series

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have dynamically changing table in Excel and need for a bubble chart to automatically be based off the table even when data changes. The key is that each ROW in the table represents a series to be in the bubble chart.

```
Series A   5   10    5%
Series B   4    8    3%
.
.
```

I understand how to use dynamic ranges without VBA for bubble but since I need to create/update dynamic series from my research I need to use VBA. I have written the following code but am getting error message that the chart can't be found even though I have checked 50 times I have the correct name

I need the VBA code, to reference the Existing chart on Sheet11, and update it (add/edit) based on table.

My code:

```
Public Sub CreateMultiSeriesBubbleChart()
  Dim bubbleChart As ChartObject
  Set bubbleChart = Sheet11.ChartObjects("Chart 13") ''verified i have chart 13 on sheet 11

  Dim r As Integer
  For r = 2 To 201
    With bubbleChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "=" & Sheet11.Cells(r, 1).Address(External:=True)
        .XValues = Sheet11.Cells(r, 2).Address(External:=True)
        .Values = Sheet11.Cells(r, 3).Address(External:=True)
        .BubbleSizes = Sheet11.Cells(r, 4).Address(External:=True)
    End With
  Next

  bubbleChart.Chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
  bubbleChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "=" & Sheet11.Cells(1, 2).Address(External:=True)

  bubbleChart.Chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
  bubbleChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "=" & Sheet11.Cells(1, 3).Address(External:=True)
  ''bubbleChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
  ''bubbleChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
  ''bubbleChart.Chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMajor)
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this code provides error on Set bubbleChart line saying 'Application defined or Object defined error'. I can use very similar code to create a new chart so I figure the rest works properly but I can't reference existing chart which is what I need to be able to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way your referencing your sheet.  Use `Sheets("Sheet11")` instead of `Sheet11`

Try this:

```
Set bubbleChart = Sheets("Sheet11").ChartObjects("Chart 13")
```

---

Note that you can call the name or the index this way.  For example:

```
Sheets("MySheetName").select
```

or

```
Sheets(11).select
```